# Python Validator function for phone and email

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-validation

I have a website to validate spreadsheet headers and rows when a spreadsheet is uploaded to the site, here I have some validation function where I will have to validate the rows according the attributes of the field in my case I have model like below:

**models.py**

```
from phone_field.models import PhoneField

class Add(Model):
    phone = PhoneField(max_length=255)
    a_1 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    ad_2 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    town = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
```

I need to write the custom validators for phone and email while uploading the spreadsheet.

```
def phone_validator(value):
    # code: ...
def email_validator(value):
    # code: ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You **don't** have to write validators. The entire point of an `EmailField` and a `PhoneField` is that it contains validators. For example an [**`EmailField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#emailfield) is:

> A [`CharField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.CharField) that checks that the value is a valid email address using [`EmailValidator`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/validators/#django.core.validators.EmailValidator).

The `EmailField` will thus validate that the value entered is an email address.

You furthermore do *not* have to validate [**`unique=True`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#unique) either:

> This is **enforced** at the database level and **by model validation**. If you try to save a model with a duplicate value in a unique field, a `django.db.IntegrityError` will be raised by the model’s `save()` method.

So Django will automatically validate the uniqness as well.

For a `PhonreField`, it will; not add validation by default, since there are a lot of ways to specify a phone number. If you want to only allow phone numbers by the [*E.164* standard [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.164), you can set `E164_only=True` for that field:

```
from phone_field.models import PhoneField

class Address(BaseModel):
    phone = PhoneField(E164_only=True, blank=True)
    # …
```

but personally I would not do that. If you do not set the [**`max_length=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.CharField.max_length), it will use `max_length=31`, which is likely sufficient for a phone number. The length is *also* validated. Indeed, as the documentation on the [`max_length=…` parameter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.CharField.max_length) says:

> Required. The maximum length (in characters) of the field. The **`max_length` is enforced at the database level and in Django’s validation** using [MaxLengthValidator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/validators/#django.core.validators.MaxLengthValidator).

So to summarize, only for a field that requires some non-standard validation, you need to implement a custom validator.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the Django document about the validators

```
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/validators/
```

also, you can use this one

```
https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/63699/django.core.validators.validate_email
```